# Integer digits in Lex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I've recently just started learning about lex and for strings, we can use the notation:

```
[a-z]+
```

while I'm curious about the case for integers. Would i be able to write something like:

```
[0-10]+
```

I'll appreciate some feedback on this as I've just started off learning Lex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would i be able to write something like:

```
[0-10]+
```

No, but you can write

```
[0-9]+
```

which is what you really mean.

This is all documented.